# jquery plugin: multiple call to a function, passing different parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've got a tricky problem.

I've made a jquery Widget plugin :

```
$.fn.Widget=function(id_place,id_event,options){};
```

I call it once when the page is ready : (specifying that I want a last sorting)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydiv').Widget(13,50,{"sort":"last"});

});
```

But in this plugin, I generate a little menu bar, with 3 links to change the sorting of my elements : "last" (initial call); "top" (most popular) and "answered" (with answers)

My question is : how to, in this generated code inside my plugin, Sort PopularSort LastSort answered,  change the sorting of my Widget??

Can I call `Widget(13,50,{"sort":"top"})` inside of it, Or can I use a inside function like `change_sorting(top)`??

Thx a lot for your time and your help

EDIT: Thanks for your answers: I've added these lines in my plugin:

```
var object = $(this);
    $(".sort_last").click(function(){ object.Widget(13,50,{"sort":"last"}); });
    $(".sort_top").click(function(){ object.Widget(13,50,{"sort":"top"}); });
    $(".sort_answered").click(function(){ object.Widget(13,50,{"sort":ansered"}); });
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but I did not understand your problem... If you generate the HTML code in your plugin it means you have access to it therefor modifiying it shoud not be a problem ?!

Comment: I just didn't know how to make the call to my plugin to change the sorting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all it is good idea to check for elements existence before creating them.
2nd - considering how other jquery methods work, best would be to use `Widget(13,50,{"sort":"top"})` for both creation and updating

Answer (score 1):

If the change in sorting is made by the user, it shouldn't be in the Widget constructor. You can easily change the value of Sort in the constructor with `options.sort = "newSort";`, but I think you want something different.

Consider adding a method to the object such as:

```
$.fn.Widget.prototype.changeSort(sort) {
  // add your sorting code here, using this.sort as the current sort
}
```

which will handle all the changing of the Sort; this way it helps abstracting the sorting mechanism from actually creating the Widget (they seem like different things to me).

If you wanted access to the current Sort in your method, you can assign it to "this" in the constructor:

`this.sort = options.sort` and then reference it with `this.sort` in any methods on the Widget prototype.

So you can then do:

```
$(function() {
  var widget = $('#mydiv').Widget(13,50,{ sort: 'last' });
  widget.changeSort("answered");
});
```

Comment: Hello Emmerich. Thanx for your answer. Can you have a glance at my edit above. I found something that actually seems to work great. What are the advantages of your method rathen than the one above?

Thx again

Comment: Well it would depend how much processing you're doing in your Widget and the semantics of it. For example, if the Widget was created once for the page and then changed it, I would go with my method. The way you have coded it means that every time the user clicks, the Widget code is executed all over again (including any Widget initialization - you're essentially overwriting the old widget with a new one, even though the data hasn't changed, just the view of the data). With mine, only the logic surrounding sorting the Widgets is run.

Comment: Ok then. I'll consider your answer if y make more complex widgets/plugins in the future. This one's just displaying sorted quotes with not much more. I'll stick with that ;)